# how to sum output of awk or other expression with xargs

Tags: bash, shell, awk, xargs

Suppose i have the following bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export  count=0;
for i in `ls ./mydoc` ;do

     pdfinfo ./mydoc/$i | egrep Pages |awk {'print $2'} |xargs -+ $count   ;
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done;

echo $count;
```

It enumarates pages of each pdf files, but i don't know how to sum them together. !!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do it in the awk, forget xargs.

```
awk '{total += $2} END {print total}'
```

but you need tto run awk only once, with all of the loop's output piped into it. And why not eliminate the separate grep too...

```
for i in mydoc/* ; do
    pdfinfo $i
done | awk '/^Pages/ { total += $2 } END { print total }'
```

Comment: @jofel I didn't notice how broken the rest of the script was. Updated with a rewrite.

Comment: well done, When you migrate completely to awk , everything ws OK.

Answer (score 3):

Try the built-in calculation method:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
for i in ./mydoc/* ; do
  count=$(( $count + $(pdfinfo "$i" | grep Pages |awk {'print $2'}) ))
done
echo $count
```

Comment: it's very nice and clean.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted `awk` answer by Alan is good, but here's a generic solution using `xargs` and `bc`.  The idea is to generate a list of numbers in some way, use `xargs` to join them all on one line separated by spaces, and then use `sed` to change the spaces to `+` characters (`tr` would work too).  pipe that into bc.

The same method can be used to construct a regexp from a list of strings/regexps, just change the spaces to `|` (extended regexp) or `\|` (basic regexp) instead of `+`:

```
for i in mydoc/* ; do pdfinfo $i ; done | \
  awk '/^Pages/ {print $2}' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

NOTE: if there are many thousands of numbers generated, exceeding the shell's command line length limit, xargs may generate multiple lines.  Since the output of `bc` qualifies as "*generate a list of numbers in some way*", the solution is to pipe the output of `bc` into `xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc` again.

```
for i in mydoc/* ; do pdfinfo $i ; done | \
  awk '/^Pages/ {print $2}' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc | \
  xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

`xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc | xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc` can, of course, be put into a shell script, function, or alias.

and here's an example of constructing a regexp using this method.  If search.txt contains foo, bar, baz, quux (one word per line) then:

```
$ cat search.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /|/g'
foo|bar|baz|quux
```

the useless-use-of-cat is a place-holder for this example - replace with any pipeline that generates a list of words or regexp patterns.

If any of the search patterns contain space characters, you'll have to change them to something else (choose something not likely to be in the input) temporarily, before piping into `xargs` and then change them back again after the `sed`.  e.g. if the 'bar' line of search.txt has a trailing space:

```
$ cat search.txt | sed -e 's/ /XXX_SPACE_CHARACTER_XXX/g' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /|/g' -e 's/XXX_SPACE_CHARACTER_XXX/ /g'
foo|bar |baz|quux
```